# Is there a way to see other Shell property sets in Explorer in Windows 7 and up?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In previous versions of Windows, when you viewed the properties of a file, there was an option to see the "Summary", which displays a standard set of properties from a Shell32 property set. There was also an "Advanced" button that would display any other non-standard property set properties. For example, when viweing a Crystal Report, we could see the properties that CR embedded as shell properties, like the report title and revision number:

[image]

In Windows 7 and up, this option is no longer there; there is instead a "Details" tab that appears to list a set of properties that depends on what Explorer thinks the file type is (e.g. images get different properties than music files.)

I'm very much hoping that these properties are just hidden somewhere and we can expose them again, since we use this information all the time for troubleshooting and version control. Short of writing an application and/or PowerShell script to extract them, is there a way to see these in current versions of Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows7, Opus File Manager shows many of the "summary info properties" from CR2008.  This [windows-explorer replacement] definitely shows some, but perhaps not all, and the names may be different.  Keywords = tags;  Author = last saved by.  Comments, Subject & Title all work.  The extended properties may be saved as "alternative data streams" ADS upon exit of CR.
But I didn't test extensively.
Opus easily sort directories by these added columns.  Opus also allows editing & searching upon these extended properties.
http://www.gpsoft.com.au/index.html

I didn't try Dmitry Brant's ADSManager  or any other file managers.
Let me know if u find something better.

Background info : http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds